# Not able to install Apache-beam package

Tags: python, apache-beam, pyarrow

Not able to install Apache-beam
error: command 'cmake' failed: None
[end of output]

ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

tried to install Apache-beam :pip install apache-beam

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @saibhargav can you check my answer please and mark it as solved if you solved your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

To install correctly `Apache Beam` `Python` on your machine, I recommend you to create a virtual env and install the package on it.

It's better to use a venv to isolate the needed packages of your project and to prevent versions conflicts.

To correctly manage the `Python` versions on your machine, you can install the [PyEnv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) tool.

**Go to the root folder of your project and create a virtual env :**

```bash
python3 -m venv <virtual-environment-name>

python3 -m venv my-env
```

`my-env` is the name of the virtual env.

**Activate this venv :**

```bash
source my-env/bin/activate
```

**At the root of your project, create a file called `requirements.txt` :**

```
apache-beam==2.46.0
```

**Run the following command :**

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
```